# Jenkins configuration using TFS plugin

Tags: jenkins, build-process, tfsbuild, build-automation

I m new to Jenkins tools
While performing configuration of build for Java project in Jenkins using tfs plugin. 
I have a placed the source code on local server on the another server machine. I have use the Visual studio 2012 as a code repository.

Im getting following error while running the build.

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\Maven TFS\workspace
FATAL: illegal URI: [192.168.1.202:8080/tfs/web/Index.asp]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal URI: [192.168.1.202:8080/tfs/web/Index.asp]
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.util.URIUtils.newURI(URIUtils.java:317)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.model.Server.<init>(Server.java:59)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.model.Server.<init>(Server.java:50)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.TeamFoundationServerScm.createServer(TeamFoundationServerScm.java:390)
    at hudson.plugins.tfs.TeamFoundationServerScm.checkout(TeamFoundationServerScm.java:237)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1269)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:607)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: 192.168.1.202:8080/tfs/web/Index.asp
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChar(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.util.URIUtils.newURI(URIUtils.java:313)
    ... 12 more
[BFA] Scanning build for known causes...
[BFA] No failure causes found
[BFA] Done. 0s
Finished: FAILURE
```

Kindly please help me to figure out the following issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URI you're using to connect to TFS is invalid
`192.168.1.202:8080/tfs/web/Index.asp` is the URI to the web UI of TFS not the source code repository

You need to use something like
`192.168.1.202:8080/tfs/defaultcollection` 
when you set up the properties of the TFS plugin

Comment: Thanks James, Actually I was passing the wrong URL for TFS server location. i have also took some help from the following url http://nkdagility.com/configuring-jenkins-talk-tfs-2013/